# JavaScript SRC reference to ip with no name

Tags: javascript, ip

im triying to make a code that loads a .js from an Ip inside of my Network the computer dosn´t have any name so i can just use the Ip, the problem its that I dont know how it works, if i need "" or just like its an Ip i just need to use later... The resource its here:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" scr=172.84.65.2/fonts.js>
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the IP to be treated as a hostname and not a directory path, then you need to either include a scheme (making it an absolute URI) or make it explicitly scheme relative:

```
//172.84.65.2/fonts.js
```

You need to be running an HTTP server. You can't use Windows File & Print Sharing for this.

You also need to spell **s**ou**rc**e correctly.

```
src="//172.84.65.2/fonts.js"
```